# MPAndroid LineChart - Change padding of the first and last x-axis values

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I've got the following line chart using MPAndroidChart:

[Print of the first X position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u4nz.png)

[Print of the last X position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB90a.png)

I'm using the following method:

```
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5)
```

Which shows only 5 values on the viewport, the rest of them will be shown by scrolling.

I'm also using this method:

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0,25,0,40);
```

Which removes the left and right offset to make the chart covers whole screen and sets top and bottom offsets to have a space between the container it's placed in.

The problem is that both, first and last position got hidden into the device border. I think if there was a way to set a padding to these individual values, the problem could be fixed.

I tried to use some methods to change the space or offset of the X-axis, but neither of them worked.

I'm trying to create [a chart like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwuT5.png) where the entire filled dataset covers whole screen, but the first and last values are placed with a padding between the border of the device and the value itself.

The entire code of my chart is down bellow:

```
    LineChart chart = view.findViewById(R.id.chartCalendar);

    // Setting up the data
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    entries.add(new Entry(1,1200));
    .....


    // Creating dataset
    LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Label"); // add entries to dataset

    // Dataset styling
    dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
    dataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
    dataSet.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getActivity(), R.color.whiteBlue));
    dataSet.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getActivity(), R.color.darkBlue));
    dataSet.setLineWidth(2); // Line border thickness
    dataSet.setCircleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getActivity(), R.color.darkBlue)); // Border circle values color

    // Setting up LineChart
    LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);

    // Styling chart
    chart.setData(lineData);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(31);
    chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5); // Show maximum 10 before scrolling
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    chart.setDrawBorders(false);// Hide the description
    chart.getXAxis().setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getActivity(), R.color.white)); // Change X-axis label color
    YAxis yAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    yAxis.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getActivity(), R.color.white)); // change Y-axis label color
    yAxis.setAxisLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getActivity(), R.color.darkBlue));
    yAxis.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getActivity(), R.color.white));
    // remove axis
    YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
    YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

    // X axis to bottom
    chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    chart.getLineData().setValueTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getActivity(), R.color.white)); // Change value color
    chart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1);
    chart.setViewPortOffsets(0,25,0,40);
    chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    // Refresh graph
    chart.animateX(500);
```

Do you guys have any idea of how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing with the same issue, did you even find the solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the first and last values from being clipped, use `your_chart.xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true)`